# How to fetch the input text value in this case

Tags: jquery

When clciked on the ADDON button , i am trying to fetch the input value of the class QtyInput

I have tried as below , but i am getting undefined .

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function(e) {

    var quantity = $(this).find(".QtyInput").val();

    alert(quantity);

});
```

I even tried with

```
var quantity = $(this).closest('.QtyInput').val(); but the same result ??
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/4/

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var quantity = $(this).closest(".Itm_dtsl").find(".QtyInput").val();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/5/)

Find will search for the child elements only. So you should get the common parent of both the elements. Here the parent element is 'Itm_dtsl'. You can use closest() method to get the specified parent.

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one quantity class this will simply do:

```
var quantity = $(".QtyInput").val();
```

This will also just directly select it rather than using any find calls.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function:

```
 $(this).siblings('div').find('.QtyInput').val();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .prev()

```
var quantity = $(this).prev().find(".QtyInput").val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5z5vzq2y/)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function() {

    var quantity = $(document).find(".QtyInput").val();

    alert(quantity);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addonsBtn', function(e) {    
   var quantity = 0;
   $(document).find('.QtyInput').each(function(){
       quantity += parseInt($(this).val()); //add all values here
   });    
   alert(quantity);   
});
```

That should work..